# Why is my code slower in pypy than the default python interpreter?

Tags: python, performance, pypy

Given a number of players `n`, I need to find `H`, the list of all tuples where each tuple is a combination of coalitions (of the players, e.g. (1,2,3) is the coalition of players 1, 2 and 3. ((1,2,3),(4,5),(6,)) is a combination of coalitions - which are also tuples) that respects this rule: each player appears only and exactly once (i.e. in only one coalition).
P.S. Each combination of coalitions is called layout in the code.

At the beginning I wrote a snippet in which I computed all combinations of all coalitions and for each combination I checked the rule. Problem is that for 5-6 players the number of combinations of coalitions was already so big that my computer went phut.
In order to avoid a a big part of the computation (all possible combinations, the loop and the ifs) I wrote the following (which I tested and it's equivalent to the previous snippet):

```
from itertools  import combinations, combinations_with_replacement, product, permutations

players = range(1,n+1)
coalitions = [[coal for coal in list(combinations(players,length))] for length in players]

H = [tuple(coalitions[0]),(coalitions[-1][0],)]
combs = [comb for length in xrange(2,n) for comb in combinations_with_replacement(players,length) if sum(comb) == n]
perms = list(permutations(players))
layouts = set(frozenset(frozenset(perm[i:i+x]) for (i,x) in zip([0]+[sum(comb[:y]) for y in xrange(1,len(comb))],comb)) for comb in combs for perm in perms)
H.extend(tuple(tuple(tuple(coal) for coal in layout) for layout in layouts))
print H
```

EXPLANATION: say n = 3

First I create all possible coalitions:

```
coalitions = [[(1,),(2,),(3,)],[(1,2),(1,3),(2,3)],[(1,2,3)]]
```

Then I initialize H with the obvious combinations: each player in his own coalition and every player in the biggest coalition.

```
H = [((1,),(2,),(3,)),((1,2,3),)]
```

Then I compute all the possible forms of the layouts:

```
combs = [(1,2)]   #(1,2) represents a layout in which there is 
                  #one 1-player coalition and one 2-player coalition.
```

I compute the permutations (perms).
Finally for each perm and for each comb I calculate the different possible layouts. I `set` the result (`layouts`) in order to delete duplicates and add to H.

```
H = [((1,),(2,),(3,)),((1,2,3),),((1,2),(3,)),((1,3),(2,)),((2,3),(1,))]
```

Here's the comparison:

`python script.py`

- 4: 0.000520944595337 seconds
- 5: 0.0038321018219 seconds
- 6: 0.0408189296722 seconds
- 7: 0.431486845016 seconds
- 8: 6.05224680901 seconds
- 9: 76.4520540237 seconds

`pypy script.py`

- 4: 0.00342392921448 seconds
- 5: 0.0668039321899 seconds
- 6: 0.311077833176 seconds
- 7: 1.13124799728 seconds
- 8: 11.5973010063 seconds
- 9: went phut

Why is pypy that slower? What should I change?

Comment: Regular itertools might use faster compiled code.

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean with regular?

Comment: your default interpreter

Comment: I see. Should I report this to pypy creators?

Comment: They know about these differences.

Comment: you can also add some optimizations, for example went you build `coalitions` you don't need to call `list` on `combinations` and in `H.extend` you don't need the outer most call to tuple. In those instances you lose time and memory build a intermediary list/tuple that you don't really use or need.

Comment: just write a loop. It's gonna be massively massively faster

Comment: As fijal says, a loop is the way to go. I've provided an answer that implements the open-coded loop and shows off the benchmark numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I want to point out that you are studying the [Bell numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number), which might ease the next part of your work, after you're done generating all the subsets. For example, it's easy to know how large each Bell set will be; OEIS has [the sequence of Bell numbers](http://oeis.org/A000110) already.

I hand-wrote the loops to generate the Bell sets; here is my code:

```py
cache = {0: (), 1: ((set([1]),),)}

def bell(x):
    # Change these lines to alter memoization.
    if x in cache:
        return cache[x]
    previous = bell(x - 1)
    new = []
    for sets in previous:
        r = []
        for mark in range(len(sets)):
            l = [s | set([x]) if i == mark else s for i, s in enumerate(sets)]
            r.append(tuple(l))
        new.extend(r)
        new.append(sets + (set([x]),))
    cache[x] = tuple(new)
    return new
```

I included some memoization here for practical purposes. However, by commenting out some code, and writing some other code, you can obtain the following un-memoized version, which I used for benchmarks:

```py
def bell(x):
    if x == 0:
        return ()
    if x == 1:
        return ((set([1]),),)
    previous = bell(x - 1)
    new = []
    for sets in previous:
        r = []
        for mark in range(len(sets)):
            l = [s | set([x]) if i == mark else s for i, s in enumerate(sets)]
            r.append(tuple(l))
        new.extend(r)
        new.append(sets + (set([x]),))
    cache[x] = tuple(new)
    return new
```

My numbers are based on a several-year-old Thinkpad that I do most of my work on. Most of the smaller cases are way too fast to measure reliably (not even a single millisecond per trial for the first few), so my benchmarks are testing `bell(9)` through `bell(11)`.

Benchmarks for CPython 2.7.11, using the standard `timeit` module:

```
$ python -mtimeit -s 'from derp import bell' 'bell(9)'
10 loops, best of 3: 31.5 msec per loop
$ python -mtimeit -s 'from derp import bell' 'bell(10)'
10 loops, best of 3: 176 msec per loop
$ python -mtimeit -s 'from derp import bell' 'bell(11)'
10 loops, best of 3: 1.07 sec per loop
```

And on PyPy 4.0.1, also using `timeit`:

```
$ pypy -mtimeit -s 'from derp import bell' 'bell(9)'
100 loops, best of 3: 14.3 msec per loop
$ pypy -mtimeit -s 'from derp import bell' 'bell(10)'
10 loops, best of 3: 90.8 msec per loop
$ pypy -mtimeit -s 'from derp import bell' 'bell(11)'
10 loops, best of 3: 675 msec per loop
```

So, the conclusion that I've come to is that `itertools` is not very fast when you try to use it outside of its intended idioms. Bell numbers are interesting combinatorically but they do not naturally arise from any simple composition of `itertools` widgets that I can find.

In response to your original query of what to do to make it faster: Just open-code it. Hope this helps!

~ C.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Corbin ! But I still have 2 issues: 1. although your code is way faster than mine, when I use it with pypy it's still slower. 2. I want a list of tuples of tuples, not of tuples of sets: I tried to modify it but I can't apply tuple() to sets. Can you change it please?

Comment: To be more precise: it's important  that each tuple (coalition) inside another tuple (layout) has its elements in order (Ex: (1,2,3) is ok, (3,1,2) is not) since I use the coalitions in other parts of the code for other purposes

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Pypy issue on `itertools.product`.

https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/issues/1677/itertoolsproduct-slower-than-nested-fors

> Note that our goal is to ensure that itertools is not massively slower than
>   plain Python, but we don't really care about making it exactly as fast (or
>   faster) as plain Python.  As long as it's not massively slower, it's fine.  (At
>   least I don't agree with you about whether a) or b) is easier to read :-)

Without studying your code in detail, it looks like it makes heavy use of the `itertools` combinations, permutations and product functions.  In regular CPython those are written in compiled C code, with the intention of making them fast.  Pypy does not implement the C code, so it shouldn't be surprising that these functions are slower.

Comment: PyPy's implementation of `itertools` is not in plain Python, though.

Comment: `pypy / pypy / module / itertools / interp_itertools.py` - the code for `combinations`, for example, looks like iterative Python.  I assume it's designed to take advantage of the `jit`.